# Couldn't find any package by regex 'teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, teamviewer

i want to install team-viewer in ubuntu
i try this command

```
apt install teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb
```

and i get this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably if you just try to install teamviewer from apt-get you will see some problems to solve. first off all do some commands:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install

sudo apt autoremove
```

these commands will correct all the dependence problems. after all you have to use this simple command:

```
sudo apt-get install teamviewer
```

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer for Debian is only 32bits so you need to install Multiarch 32bits first.

```
1)dpkg --add-architecture i386

2)apt-get update
```

Install Teamviewer

```
3)dpkg -i '/home/user/Downloads/teamviewer_i386.deb'

Install missing library

4)apt-get install -f
```

If necessary install Teamviewer again.

```
Click on Teamviewer icon to run.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try install using `./` before the name of the package?

Example:

```
apt install ./teamviewer_13.1.3026_amd64.deb          # code indented
```

This works for me.

Comment: You can format your code as follows: (1) In-line code should be surrounded with backticks `\``. (2) Blocks of code should be indent with 4 spaces (you can select the code to be indented and type `ctrl+K`).